# If we have two Counter components in React, do we have to duplicate the Counter code?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In React / Redux, if our `Counter` component code is 30 lines, and let's say we want one counter to be connected to Redux store as `countNoodle` and another counter connected to Redux store as `countDrink`, do we have to duplicate that 30 lines of code?

I wasn't thinking we need CounterNoodle.js and CounterDrink.js and make the connection to Redux, and each file could be 40 lines long and it is a lot of duplicate code.

Or can we reuse the code, if `Counter` is either a class component or function component?

Answer (score 1):

Of course no, you can keep the base component the same and just create two connected components using two different [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

```
function Counter({value}) {
  return <div>{value}</div>;
}

export const CounterNoodle = connect(state => state.countNoodle)(Counter);

export const CounterDrink = connect(state => state.countDrinkg)(Counter);
```

Notice the two connected component select different part of the state, if your counter need to dispatch an action you can use `mapDispatchToProps` as the second argument

Comment: Is it true they are `connect(fnForState, fnForDispatch)(Counter)` but just different `fnForState` and `fnForDispatch`?

Comment: it seems you have to have `(Counter)` at the end of the `connect` line

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you pass in the `count` value to the  component which would allow you to pass any value into it, regardless of where it lives in the state.

Something like:

```
const countSelector = (state) => {
  return {
    drinkCount: state.drinks.total,
    noodleCount: state.noodles.total
  }
}

function App() {
  const { drinkCount, noodleCount } = useSelector(countSelector) 

return <div>
  Drink:
  <Counter count={drinkCount} />

  Noodle:
  <Counter count={noodleCount} />
</div>

}
```

If you need to subscribe the Counter component to the state, you could also do something like this:

```
const countSelector = (type) => (state) => {
  return type === 'drink' ? state.drinks.total : state.noodles.total
}

function Counter({ type }) {
  const count = useSelector(countSelector(type))

  return <div>{count}</div>
}

<Counter type="drink" />
```